# Angular.js: No controllers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I'm just trying to get a simple example going with angular but the oddness of the provisioning conventions have me stymied.

It appears I'm doing the right thing, I can see Angular in the DOM.  But it has no controllers and the dom elements that target it as a controller have been processed.

Does anyone see the glaringly stupid thing I am doing to kill the puppy?

```
var app = angular.module( 'AppModule',[] );
angular.module( 'AppModule').controller(
'AppController',
['$scope', '$log',
    function( $scope, $log ) {
        $log.warn("This is not working");
        $scope.main = {
            user : 'Scott',
            id   : 2,
            priv : 'admin'
        };
    }
]);
```

HTML code -- this is too simple to be so hard.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="AppModule">
<head>
<title>foo</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div ng-controller="AppController">
        <div >Welcome {{main.user}}</div>
            <div >level{{main.priv}}</div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<!--<script src="/lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="/lib/foo-min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I will be your best friend if you can point out what bone headed thing I am doing wrong.

Comment: Works fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/gCxyxtfh5PpXUWiiaF94?p=preview. So the JS that you posted is probably not inside /lib/foo-min.js (or angular itself is not in /lib/angular/angular.js)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how your directory structure looks like, but try without the slash

```
<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/foo-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see a little "error", it is not a determinant problem. You have:

`var app = angular.module( 'AppModule',[] );
angular.module( 'AppModule').controller(`

while it should be (note I changed angular by app):

`var app = angular.module( 'AppModule',[] );
app.controller(`

By the way, try changing your notation from this:

```
var app = angular.module( 'AppModule',[] );
app.module( 'AppModule').controller(
'AppController',
['$scope', '$log',
    function( $scope, $log ) {
        $log.warn("This is not working");
        $scope.main = {
            user : 'Scott',
            id   : 2,
            priv : 'admin'
        };
    }
]);
```

To this:

```
var app = angular.module('appModule', []);

app.controller('appController', function ($scope, $log){
    $log.warn("This is not working");
    $scope.main = {
        user : 'Scott',
        id   : 2,
        priv : 'admin'
    };

});
```

Here you can find a jsfiddle working well:
http://jsfiddle.net/ACmXR/1/

Hope to help

Answer (score -1):

Have you referenced your controller js file somewhere other than the html you're showing? If not, start by adding a reference to this at the end of you body.